# PHP error while getting multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to get all rows in database. My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lectors";

$array = array();
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql))){
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

While I send request, server doesn't reply. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you initialise your `$con` SQL connection?

Comment: Do the `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` as a single step before your `while`, and the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in the `while`.... because I'm sure you've never seen a working example or anything in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) that combines everything inside the `while`

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, in another php file: `$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and use that against your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the query in a line by itself, such as...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lectors";
$array = array();
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

Doing it in the method you are above will result in each execution of the loop executing the database query.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 5):

```
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql))){
```

This is a never ending loop, your query will execute fine every time and loop will never terminate.

*Need I say further?*

It is only as good as

```
while(true)
{
   // keep querying my database until i run out of resources
}
```

Execute the query first and loop over its result only.

**And Oh,**

> While I send request, server doesn't reply

Because, as i said; It is busy running in a circle, has no time to reply.

Comment: But my code works fine with loop. My problem was in lines, see below answer.

Comment: Nope it doesn't.  If you did understand, that answer speaks this same language. Just that it provides a copy paste solution without much of an explanation so it fixes your problem but you still don't know what the problem was :)